# Laravel Permissions query cache

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am using Laravel Permissions package (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) for managing role-permission on the Laravel project.

On every page of the application the i can see from the Laravel debugger that the follow two queries is running. Roles and Permissions have not changed so often and i want to cache these queries. Can you please let me know how can i do so?

```
select `roles`.*, `model_has_roles`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `model_has_roles`.`model_type` as `pivot_model_type` from `roles` inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `model_has_roles`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\User'

select `permissions`.*, `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` as `pivot_permission_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` as `pivot_model_type` from `permissions` inner join `model_has_permissions` on `permissions`.`id` = `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` where `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\User'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this package](https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-eloquent-query-cache) to cache your query. 
To enable caching on specific query you can do something like:

```
DB::cacheFor(now()->addHours(24))->raw('YOUR QUERY GOES HERE');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue is the query is running form the package itself. I can cache my application queries without any additional packages. 
I was searching a solution when i can use the permission package and cache these generic query.

Comment: I don't believe you can cache generic queries by default. The best you can do with this package is caching entire Models using `QueryCacheable`trait that this package provides, which again does not serve your purpose.

Comment: One thing you can do is to find out where Laravel Permission package is running those queries from, extend those classes and manually remember those queries.